# Update Product Attribute Options via API

Tags: magento2, rest-api

I am currently using Magento 2 api to add new product attribute with option if the type is right. When I am using the type dropdown and add some option how can I update them with the api. Their is only a POST no PUT.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the POST method to add/update attribute option. The request URL should be like this **{{base_uri}}/rest/{{store_code}}/V1/products/attributes/{{code}}/options**

with the body like:

```
{
  "option": {
    "label": "New Size Update",
    "value": "222"
  }
}
```

Magento will validate your option request and try to find the option has value (option_id) is 222 and update label to **New Size Update**. 
To know what the id of an option, you can check in the database or just need to inspect HTML element like this:
[image]
Hope this will clarify your issue

Regards

Answer (score 0):

I feel like Magento has been a bit bugged in this regard since 2.4.3.

For example. I'm trying to do a POST with the following payload and I get a 400 (bad request). The existing value is "ABSTRACT". I think Magento is not wanting me to update it, because it views the values as the same. The reason that I'm trying to update it is I used to be able to create a new value of 'Abstract' but now Magento errors when I try to do that with 400 (bad request). So I can't create a new value, and I can't update the old value. To me this is bugged, and bugged very badly.

{
"option" : {
"label" : "Abstract",
"value" : "3280"
}
}

**Side note:** You can totally do all of this in the UI, so it's just removing the functionality via the API. The API having less authority than the UI, is a bit strange in my opinion.

**Edit:**
Actually it appears to be worse than I thought. I can't update a value period. If I send a value that already exists with a new label, it still creates a new one rather than updating the existing one, though they've now added some "incorrect" validation that throws an error if the value matches an existing value when you change both to lowercase.

This leaves me with only one choice. I will have to just connect to the existing "matching" value and forget about correcting the formatting programmatically.