# REST API and custom attributes

Tags: product-attribute, rest-api

My magento installation has 3 stores (domain+language). I would like to update custom attributes for products. When I call

```
GET products/my_test_sku?storeId=1
```

i get something like the following json:

```
{
    "id": 1036,
    "sku": "my_test_sku",
    :
    "custom_attributes": [
        {
            "attribute_code": "question_color",
            "value": "#fa45a4"
        },
        :
    ]
}
```

I can not figure out how to update values for these custom attributes using some POST or PUT api call. The values are different for each storeId.

I really appreciate any help :-)
Kind regards - Mikkel

Comment: Check this one . May be help for you https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/255398/update-product-attribute-options-via-api

Comment: Thanks Jigar. Do you also know how you would specify the storeId when calling 
PUT products/attributes/{attributeCode}

Comment: Thanks Jigar.
So to update the value for an attribute for a given product on a given store I call
PUT {{baseurl}}/rest/{{storecode}}/V1/products/attributes/{{attributecode}}
 - How do I specify the product sku and attribute value? I guess they need to be placed in the body - I have tried to format some json but with no luck :-(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer my own question.
For a multi store magento 2 setup you can update of a custom attribute for a given product like this:

```
PUT {{base_uri}}/rest/{{store_code}}/V1/products/{{sku}}
{
  "Product": {
    "Custom_attributes": [
      {
         "Attribute_code": "some code",
         "Value": "some value"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Thanks Jigar